# Can't connect to remote MS SQL Server Database

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion, connection, datasource

I have a MS SQL Server Database in house (but on a different network) that I am trying to connect to via cold fusion. However I keep getting this error: "Datasource could not be found."

- Remote connections are enabled including tcpip.
- Account name is correct. I can log in via test without any problems.

Here is my code:

```
<cfquery 
  name="getIT" 
  datasource="RemoteServerName_OR_ipAddress.DATABASE_NAME.dbo"
  username="test" 
  password="test"
>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you need to set up the datasource in the Coldfusion Administrator.

http://www.quackit.com/coldfusion/tutorial/coldfusion_datasource.cfm

Answer (score 3):

You need to first set up the datasource in ColdFusion Administrator, then use the datasource name - see the documentation [adding data sources](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Admin/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbf3639b1-7ffc.html)